# Computer freezes after trying start react app

Tags: reactjs, git-bash

I was working on an react app and after I added a HOC and saved it my Chrome browser, it took a while to reload and then suddenly my computer froze. I did a hard reset and tried to start the app and the same thing happened. I even removed the component altogether and the app still won't start and my computer froze again.

Any idea why this is happening?

This the second time I've been working on this project and at about the same point my computer started to act up again. The first time I deleted all my project files and started over and now it's doing it again.

Comment: You should be adding more details to your question, welcome to stackoverflow, please read, how to ask section.

Comment: I don't know what more details to add. I tried to be as specific as possible